# Is there a better to get last element of an absolute path in java?

Tags: java, path

I have many strings like this `D:\just\a\path`, the string might differ in number of elements, maybe `C:\just\another\longer\path`.

I want to get the last element `path`. 
I tried using `substring`:

```
myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

and `Path`:

```
nameo1 = Paths.get(string).getName(Paths.get(string).getNameCount() -1); //-1 because of root
```

but second method seems not to work with all operating system.

My question is: Is there any better, more elegant method to get exactly what I want?

NOTE: the final element is a directory, a folder, not a file. So `new File(string).getName()` won't work and just return nothing.

Edit: It was my bad. sometimes the string is empty so it return nothing. Cost me an hour working with it.
Edit2: Some file paths contain white space, thus this method return an empty string

Comment: `new File(string).getName()` does work for folders!

Comment: Maybe the "newer" Path API helps you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: When you said `new File(path).getName()` doesn't work, were you trying it on a path like `c:\temp\ ` with a trailing slash?

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad. sometimes the string is empty so it return nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can (and nowadays should) use [`java.nio.file.Path.getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()), which works like this for paths to files or directories (no matter if the `String` ends with a backslash or not):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pathStringToAFile = "U:\\temp\\TestOutput\\TestFolder\\test_file.txt";
    String pathStringToAFolder = "U:\\temp\\TestOutput\\TestFolder";
    String pathStringToAFolderWithTrailingBackslash = "U:\\temp\\TestOutput\\TestFolder\\";

    Path pathToAFile = Paths.get(pathStringToAFile);
    Path pathToAFolder = Paths.get(pathStringToAFolder);
    Path pathToAFolderWithTrailingBackslash 
                        = Paths.get(pathStringToAFolderWithTrailingBackslash);

    System.out.println(pathToAFile.getFileName().toString());
    System.out.println(pathToAFolder.getFileName().toString());
    System.out.println(pathToAFolderWithTrailingBackslash.getFileName().toString());
}
```

This outputs

```
test_file.txt
TestFolder
TestFolder
```

Comment: Even when the question is kind of off-topic because of my fault. This is still a nice answer.

Comment: i didnt get same output. it comes with full path only

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.split:

```
    String path = "D:\just\a\path";
    String[] directories = path.split("\");
    String last = directories[directories.size-1];
```

Comment: Don't use `"\"` specifically.  Use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Get last Directory of a path:

`Paths.get(path).getParent().getFileName();`

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String str = "C:\\just\\another\\longer\\path\\";
    // String str = "/path/with/right/slashes/works/too/";
       String str = "C:\\and\\path\\with/mixed/slashes/works/too/";

    // String str = "C:\\just\\another\\longer\\path";
    // String str = "/path/with/right/slashes/works/too";
    // String str = "C:\\and\\path\\with/mixed/slashes/works/too";

    String name = Paths.get(str.replace('\\', '/')).toFile().getName();

    System.out.println("name = " + name);

  }
```